# NAT64 enabled on OSX, iPhone still gets an IPv4 IP Address

Tags: macos, iphone, network, wifi, ipv6

I've enabled the "Create NAT64 Network" option in network "Sharing". I connect my iPhone and it seems to work (tested in Safari). However, when I look at the Wi-Fi information for the connection my IP address is an IPv4 one (or at least has that format)

- IP Address: 169.254.34.19
- Mask: 255.255.0.0
- DNS: 2001:2:0:aab1::1

The DNS has a v6 address, but I was expecting the device itself to also get such an address.

How can I be certain I have a IPv6 only connection, and possible how can I get such an address?  I'm trying to test connectivity of an App to be distributed in the App Store.

Comment: This looks correct.

Answer (score 3):

Addresses starting with 169.254 are called [APIPA or link-local](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) addresses. It's what your interface automatically gets when the DHCP client is enabled but no DHCP server can be found. They are not usable to connect to the internet.

Don't worry, it seems that your test environment is IPv6-only.

Comment: Remember this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37498492/1068283

Comment: Good reminder :)